# Share Extension in SwiftUI project not showing on the Mac

Tags: macos, share-extension

I've implemented a share extension for my iOS app to send it URL's from safari. It works great on iOS.  My app is also able to run on OSX using the iPad layout.. On the Mac my app doesn't show up in the share sheet on the Mac from Safari.. is that possible using my swiftUI app.. not AppKit